# How to center the 2D Cursor in the UV Editor (Quickly)?

Tags: uv, interface, workflow, shortcut

Is there a way to center the 2D Cursor to the *UV Editor* (Quickly)? Similar to pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the default *3D Viewport*?

Comment: For really quick way without selecting anything in UV map, directly enter values for 3D Cursor position (in the Properties panel > *Display*)

Comment: With *Normalized* option enabled you can set the cursor location values to `0.5`. Is this fast enough?

Comment: @poor I never knew about the Normalized option. I was really hoping for a keyboard short cut though. At least I can be precise with your and Mr Zaks responses. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Centering the cursor in the UV Editor window can be used in the same way like in the viewport.

Use shortcut <kbd>Schift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to do this.

Confirmed in Blender 3.2.1.